# Text clean up in Python

Tags: python, string, resource-cleanup

I'm new to Python and can't find a way to remove useless text. The main purpose is to keep the word I want and remove all the rest.  At this stage, I can check my **in_data** and find the word I want. If **sentence.find(wordToCheck)** is positive, then keep it. The **in_data** is sentence each row, but the current output is a word each line. What I want is remain the formats, find the word in each row and remove the rest.

```
import Orange
import orange

word = ['roaming','overseas','samsung']
out_data = []

for i in range(len(in_data)):
    for j in range(len(word)):
        sentence = str(in_data[i][0])
        wordToCheck = word[j]
        if(sentence.find(wordToCheck) >= 0):
            print wordToCheck
```

output

```
roaming
overseas
roaming
overseas
roaming
overseas
samsung
samsung
```

The **in_data** is sentence like

```
contacted vodafone about going overseas and asked about roaming charges. The customer support officer says there isn't a charge but while checking my usage overseas.
```

I expect to see the output is like

```
overseas roaming overseas
```

Comment: The in_data is a sentence like this:   "Contacted vodafone about going overseas and asked about roaming charges. The customer support officer says there isn't a charge but while checking my usage overseas."     The output I expect is "overseas roaming overseas"

Comment: whats that.. what is ur in_data?

Comment: please share ur in_data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> word = ['roaming','overseas','samsung']
>>> s =  "Contacted vodafone about going overseas and asked about roaming charges. The customer support officer says there isn't a charge but while checking my usage overseas."
>>> pattern = r'|'.join(map(re.escape, word))
>>> re.findall(pattern, s)
['overseas', 'roaming', 'overseas']
>>> ' '.join(_)
'overseas roaming overseas'
```

Non-regex approach would be to use `str.join` with `str.strip` and a generator expression. The strip() call is required to get rid of the punctuations like `'.'`, `','` etc.

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> ' '.join(y for y in (x.strip(punctuation) for x in s.split()) if y in word)
'overseas roaming overseas'
```

Comment: Hah mine is the reverse of this :)

Comment: I mean, you _can_ use regex for it. But it is not exactly "best-practice" or pythonic, especially for a problem as simple as this.

Comment: However, I admit, I hadn't considered it to be puntuations and symbols in the string. In that case it is not too stupid :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get some idea about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it much simpler, like this:

```
for w in in_data.split():
    if w in word:
        print w
```

Here we first split the `in_data` by spaces, which returns a list of words. We then loop through each word in the in data and check if the word equals one of those you are looking for. If it does, then we print it.

And, for even faster lookup, make the `word`-list a set instead. Much faster.

In addition, if you want to handle punctuations and symbols you need to either use regex or check if all characters in the string is a letter. So, to get the output you want:

```
import string
in_words = ('roaming','overseas','samsung')
out_words = []

for w in in_data.split():
    w = "".join([c for c in w if c in string.letters])
    if w in in_words:
        out_words.append(w)
" ".join(out_words)
```

Comment: This won't give the desired output.

Comment: `in_words` should be a set for faster lookup, i.e. constructed with `in_words = set(['roaming','overseas','samsung'])`, iirc tuple lookups are slightly slower than lists.

Comment: I use python script in Orange, after I try this, it give AttributeError: 'Orange.data.Table' has no attribute 'split'
>>>

Comment: @user3705931: I do not know what `Orange` is. But `in_data` is a string? You need to tell us more about the `in_data` if `.split()` does not work.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Yes it does?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: He/she wants an output as a string seperated by spaces. You return a list.

Comment: @hermansc    in_data is a array, it got two column and the sentence is in first column.   Sorry I am new to coding.

Comment: This answer doesn't handle punctuation, since it uses `split()`. E.g. the word "overseas." won't get picked up, due to the full stop at the end.

Comment: @DaveChallis: You are right. I added handling for that as well now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler way:

```
>>> import re
>>> i
"Contacted vodafone about going overseas and asked about roaming charges. The customer support officer says there isn't a charge but while checking my usage overseas."
>>> words
['roaming', 'overseas', 'samsung']
>>> [w for w in re.findall(r"[\w']+", i) if w in words]
['overseas', 'roaming', 'overseas']
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer using split will fall over on punctuation.  You need to break up the words with a regular expression.

```
import re

in_data = "contacted vodafone about going overseas and asked about roaming charges. The customer support officer says there isn't a charge but while checking my usage overseas."

word = ['roaming','overseas','samsung']
out_data = []

word_re = re.compile(r'[^\w\']+')
for check_word in word_re.split(in_data):
  if check_word in word:
    print check_word
```